# How do I configure ifort on a personal workstation?

Tags: linux

I've been getting into some heavy numerical work lately, so I went ahead and installed [Intel Parallel Studio](http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intel-parallel-studio-xe-2013-for-linux-documentation) on Debian 7.

Unfortunately to use any of the installed software, I need to source a number of set up scripts in `/opt/intel/bin` which is inconvenient to do manually every time I want to use the compiler. I could write a script to do this automatically for me, but as far as I know that won't work for launching the GUI applications *from* a GUI.

Is there a standard way to configure the Intel install to remain readily available for use on a personal workstation?

Answer (score 1):

You can add your source commands to your .bashrc. I have the following lines in my .bashrc

Intel 2011

> source /opt/intel/composer_xe_2011_sp1/bin/compilervars.sh intel64

Intel 2013

> source /opt/intel/composer_xe_2013.3.163/bin/compilervars.sh intel64

Take a look at the Intel compiler installation steps in this link http://www.ansci.wisc.edu/morota/R/intel/intel-compiler.html